VSCode Remote SSH - failed: Error: No route to host
I am trying to remote ssh into Raspberry Pi (latest operating system with all upgrades). I am getting the following error
failed: Error: No route to host
Note: I am able to successfully remote SSH from Mac terminal.
SSH from VS code terminal is failing too.
ssh Lily@Lilac.local
ssh: connect to host lilac.local port 22: Undefined error: 0

Full output
[09:26:07.834] Log Level: 2
[09:26:07.844] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616005223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d", attempt 1
[09:26:07.845] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[09:26:07.845] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[09:26:07.845] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[09:26:07.845] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[09:26:07.845] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[09:26:07.846] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[09:26:07.846] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[09:26:07.846] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[09:26:07.846] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[09:26:07.846] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[09:26:07.846] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[09:26:07.846] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[09:26:07.847] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[09:26:07.847] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[09:26:07.847] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[09:26:07.847] "remote.SSH.permitPtyAllocation": false
[09:26:07.847] "remote.SSH.preferredLocalPortRange: undefined
[09:26:07.847] "remote.SSH.useCurlAndWgetConfigurationFiles: false
[09:26:07.858] VS Code version: 1.93.1
[09:26:07.858] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.114.3
[09:26:07.859] darwin x64
[09:26:07.860] SSH Resolver called for host: Lilac.local
[09:26:07.860] Setting up SSH remote "Lilac.local"
[09:26:07.863] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxjnnj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-5e26f877-install.lock
[09:26:07.865] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/neptune/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-5e26f877-38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40-0.114.3-es/data.json
[09:26:07.865] No existing data file
[09:26:07.865] Using commit id "38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40" and quality "stable" for server
[09:26:07.867] Script variables:
 {
  "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
  "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
  "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
  "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
  "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
  "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
  "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
  "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
  "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
  "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
  "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
  "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
  "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
  "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
  "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
  "uuid": "6353def35478",
  "startMarker": "6353def35478: running",
  "commitId": "38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40",
  "quality": "stable",
  "token": "a1a111aa-a11a-111a-a11a-11a1a1a1aa11",
  "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
  "allowClientDownload": "1",
  "forceClientDownload": "0",
  "cliNameInArchive": "code",
  "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
  "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
  "wgetTriesSegment": "--tries=1",
  "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
  "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "6353def35478:trigger_server_download",
  "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "6353def35478:trigger_server_download_end",
  "getProgressDownloading": "6353def35478%%1%%",
  "getProgressInstalling": "6353def35478%%2%%"
}
[09:26:07.870] Install and start server if needed
[09:26:07.872] PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
[09:26:07.872] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[09:26:07.890] > OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6

[09:26:07.894] askpass server listening on /var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-893ed7068401ad57552f6d011da471570451d18d.sock
[09:26:07.894] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-475f8fd3c8ebce1b7979c6a620be016ac42f9c2d.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","55769","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","Lilac.local"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/neptune/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-5e26f877-38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40-0.114.3-es/data.json"}
[09:26:07.895] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zIB4Zu95iz/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-893ed7068401ad57552f6d011da471570451d18d.sock"}
[09:26:07.896] Spawned 11289
[09:26:08.090] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 55769 -o ConnectTimeout=15 Lilac.local
[09:26:08.093] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=11296
[09:26:08.105] stderr> OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[09:26:08.384] stderr> ssh: connect to host lilac.local port 22: No route to host
[09:26:08.385] > local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down
[09:26:08.392] Local server exit: 0
[09:26:08.393] Received install output: local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 55769 -o ConnectTimeout=15 Lilac.local
local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=11296
OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
ssh: connect to host lilac.local port 22: No route to host
local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down

[09:26:08.395] Resolver error: Error: No route to host
    at v.Offline (/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:501455)
    at /Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:497518
    at t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:497661)
    at e (/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:553052)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:575341
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:579017)
    at async /Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:549757
    at async T (/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:547808)
    at async t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:549297)
    at async k (/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:572473)
    at async t.resolve (/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:576428)
    at async /Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:844803
[09:26:08.399] ------




[09:26:08.952] Opening exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73700e616d65223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d
[09:26:08.968] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-5e26f877-install.lock
[09:26:08.968] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73700e616d65223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d
[09:26:08.971] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/neptune/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-5e26f877-38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40-0.114.3-es/data.json
[09:26:08.985] Opening exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73700e616d65223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d
[09:26:08.986] No existing data file
[09:26:08.986] Using commit id "38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40" and quality "stable" for server
[09:26:08.999] Script variables:
 {
  "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
  "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
  "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
  "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
  "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
  "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
  "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
  "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
  "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
  "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
  "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
  "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
  "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
  "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
  "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
  "uuid": "145c87f9dce5",
  "startMarker": "145c87f9dce5: running",
  "commitId": "38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40",
  "quality": "stable",
  "token": "1aaa1111-1111-1111-111a-111aa11aa11a",
  "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
  "allowClientDownload": "1",
  "forceClientDownload": "0",
  "cliNameInArchive": "code",
  "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
  "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
  "wgetTriesSegment": "--tries=1",
  "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
  "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "145c87f9dce5:trigger_server_download",
  "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "145c87f9dce5:trigger_server_download_end",
  "getProgressDownloading": "145c87f9dce5%%1%%",
  "getProgressInstalling": "145c87f9dce5%%2%%"
}
[09:26:09.000] Install and start server if needed
[09:26:09.125] askpass server listening on /var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-6c7a97dc6fb9d32942bbb16edd763bc6837d0405.sock
[09:26:09.126] Spawning local server with {"serverId":2,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-0fcb5bdca352c88cea7db1f5cfda532fd10f5516.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","55769","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","Lilac.local"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/neptune/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-5e26f877-38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40-0.114.3-es/data.json"}
[09:26:09.126] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zIB4Zu95iz/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-6c7a97dc6fb9d32942bbb16edd763bc6837d0405.sock"}
[09:26:09.127] Spawned 11299
[09:26:09.329] > local-server-2> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 55769 -o ConnectTimeout=15 Lilac.local
[09:26:09.333] > local-server-2> Spawned ssh, pid=11306
[09:26:09.345] stderr> OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[09:26:09.349] stderr> ssh: connect to host lilac.local port 22: No route to host
[09:26:09.352] > local-server-2> ssh child died, shutting down
[09:26:09.360] Local server exit: 0
[09:26:09.361] Received install output: local-server-2> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 55769 -o ConnectTimeout=15 Lilac.local
local-server-2> Spawned ssh, pid=11306
OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
ssh: connect to host lilac.local port 22: No route to host
local-server-2> ssh child died, shutting down

[09:26:09.362] Exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73700e616d65223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d failed: Error: No route to host
[09:26:09.362] Existing exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73700e616d65223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d errored (Error: No route to host)
[09:26:09.362] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-5e26f877-install.lock
[09:26:09.362] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73700e616d65223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d
[09:26:09.363] Error opening exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73700e616d65223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d: Error: No route to host
[09:26:09.363] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/neptune/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-5e26f877-38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40-0.114.3-es/data.json
[09:26:09.364] No existing data file
[09:26:09.364] Using commit id "38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40" and quality "stable" for server
[09:26:09.366] Script variables:
 {
  "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
  "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
  "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
  "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
  "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
  "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
  "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
  "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
  "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
  "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
  "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
  "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
  "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
  "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
  "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
  "uuid": "9934211430c9",
  "startMarker": "9934211430c9: running",
  "commitId": "38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40",
  "quality": "stable",
  "token": "111a1111-a111-1a1a-aa1a-11aaa1111a11",
  "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
  "allowClientDownload": "1",
  "forceClientDownload": "0",
  "cliNameInArchive": "code",
  "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
  "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
  "wgetTriesSegment": "--tries=1",
  "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
  "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "9934211430c9:trigger_server_download",
  "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "9934211430c9:trigger_server_download_end",
  "getProgressDownloading": "9934211430c9%%1%%",
  "getProgressInstalling": "9934211430c9%%2%%"
}
[09:26:09.368] Install and start server if needed
[09:26:09.372] askpass server listening on /var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-0e6c4eff8c06ed23443f6848fd4c0a19b68094c4.sock
[09:26:09.373] Spawning local server with {"serverId":3,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-5f62d0c5d240ed519029481cc905f8010fa9e3ee.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","55769","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","Lilac.local"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/neptune/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-5e26f877-38c31bc77e0nn6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40-0.114.3-es/data.json"}
[09:26:09.373] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zIB4Zu95iz/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/neptune/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/v4/hrbl1rxj7yj3_3xddd8wh6zc0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-0e6c4eff8c06ed23443f6848fd4c0a19b68094c4.sock"}
[09:26:09.374] Spawned 11307
[09:26:09.564] > local-server-3> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 55769 -o ConnectTimeout=15 Lilac.local
[09:26:09.568] > local-server-3> Spawned ssh, pid=11314
[09:26:09.580] stderr> OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[09:26:09.584] stderr> ssh: connect to host lilac.local port 22: No route to host
[09:26:09.586] > local-server-3> ssh child died, shutting down
[09:26:09.592] Local server exit: 0
[09:26:09.593] Received install output: local-server-3> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 55769 -o ConnectTimeout=15 Lilac.local
local-server-3> Spawned ssh, pid=11314
OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
ssh: connect to host lilac.local port 22: No route to host
local-server-3> ssh child died, shutting down

[09:26:09.594] Exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73700e616d65223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d failed: Error: No route to host
[09:26:09.594] Error opening exec server for ssh-remote+7b22686f73700e616d65223a224c696c61632e6c6f63616c227d: Error: No route to host

I tried downgrading VSCode and the SSH Remote plugin based on the net research. Reinstalled Raspberry Pi operating system and set up SSH.
Additionally VS Code terminal :
ssh Lily@Lilac.local -v

OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/neptune/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/neptune/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for Lilac.local
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to lilac.local port 22.
ssh: connect to host lilac.local port 22: Undefined error: 0


If you are on Mac (Sequoia), see this answer.
TL;DR:

Settings>Privacy & Security>Local Network and allow VS Code


Thanks Neeth, been struggling with it for a few days now. Yes I have upgraded to Sequoia and VS code worked after the settings update.

Leaving all the Karma points here that are possible on SO :)

omg thanks, wasted most of my night trying to figure this out, would be nice if someone Microsoft / Apple would document this ...

Thanks, this solution saved me ton of time
